# How to pass a config file as parameter to a console application .Net

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, console-application

I need a sample/example demonstrating how to pass a config file as a parameter to a console application in .Net

Comment: What kind of config file? Do you mean the ProgramName.exe.config file? Why not just pass the filename as a parameter? What did you try? What problem did you have?

Comment: The file will have configuration settings like FileOutputDirectory etc and it can be located on any physical location like C:\file.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it in command line parameters, in `args[]`.
Something like this.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("args is null."); // Check for null array
        }
        else
        {
            // use args to get passed config file path
        }
    }
}
```

~~~ How to call the program ~~~

> C:\ConsoleApplication1.exe "your config
>   file path" (like C:\config\app.config)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to target console application source code? Is it .NET application?

If yes do next: add target app as a reference to the source application project (exe can be added like dll, there is no difference). And call some public method.

```
// target.exe code
namespace Target {
   public class MyConfig { }

   public class Program {
      static void Main(string[] args) { }
      public static void EntryPoint(MyConfig conf) { }
   }
}

// source.exe code
namespace Source {
   class Program {
      static void Main(string[] args) {
         Target.MyConfig conf = new Target.Config();
         Target.Program.EntryPoint(conf);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to store data like FileOutputDirectory you can also use Settings page instead of config file. Settings page is easy to configure and use. Read more at msdn website: [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cftf714c%28VS.90%29.aspx)